# Laravel include project navbar from wordpress installed in the public directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

we have a /resources/views/inc/navbar.blade.php that is used in our Laravel application main layout.

We installed a Wordpress app in the /public directory.

We need to be able to use the same navbar in our ourdomain.com/blog

Any ideas in how to this can be accomplished?

Comment: Does Wordpress support Blade?

Comment: I'm sure blade can be used as stand alone. But we need to share an include from inside the Laravel directory to a blog installed in the /public directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a brainstorming:

1. You can show your blog in your laravel application (maybe html frames?).
2. You can show your navbar in your blog application (get navbar via api and render it on your wordpress template)

Comment: our blog is installed in /public

sample ourlaraveldomain.com/blog

in ourlaraveldomain.com we have a bootstrap navbar included from /resources/views/inc/navbar.blade.php.

We would like to know how to include the same navbar, on our /blog

That is outside Laravel project.

Comment: I understood. The second approach is suitable for you) You should make API route which will return your sidebar, from WordPress application you should request to this endpoint and get your navbar.

Comment: How can we return our nav so is available outside Laravel folder? or in your words how get navbar via api and render?

Comment: For example you have route '/api/get-navbar' which returns rendered navbar. From your wordpress application via ajax request you will request this navbar. And what you get you insert to some block in your wordpress page

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try that now and let you know the results.

Comment: I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think this same solution could be resolved with a regular web.php route as well

1. routes api.php

   Route::get('/wp-menu',function() {
       return view('/wp-includes/wp-menu'); 
   });
2. new view in /views/wp-includes/wp-menu.blade.php 
   (I'm excluding the css and js)

   @include('/inc.navbar')
3. Wordpress after the open body tag

on the footer before the closing body tag or you can find any of the jQuery js files

```
$(function() {
    $('#navBarContainer').load('yourdomanin.com/api/wp-navbar');
});
```

And that worked, we now have the same navbar working inside our Laravel project and our wordpress, one thing to note is that is will only work in the same domain

Comment: Important to mention that you need
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
and 
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>

In your view.

Comment: For use on other domains, you can use API middleware with a token to authenticate and your API endpoint will return JSON encoded string. So your route closure body will be like `return Response::json([view('/wp-includes/wp-menu')->render()]); ` Thank you for informing me about solution)

Comment: Thank you again for pointing that out, it might come handy, in a future project.